# Python os.stat and unicode file names

Tags: python, unicode, operating-system

In my Django application, a user has uploaded a file with a unicode character in the name.

When I'm downloading files, I'm calling :

```
os.path.exists(media)
```

to test that the file is there. This, in turn, seems to call

```
st = os.stat(path)
```

Which then blows up with the error :

UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xcf' in position 92: ordinal not in range(128)

What can I do about this? Is there an option to path.exists to handle it?

Update : Actually, all I had to do was encode the argument to exists, ie.

```
os.path.exists(media.encode('utf-8')
```

Thanks everyone who answered.

Comment: The problem with your solution is that its not portable. os.path.exists should transparently handle the encoding based on the OS locale.

Answer (score 9):

I'm assuming you're in Unix.  If not, please remember to say which OS you're in.

Make sure your locale is set to UTF-8.  All modern Linux systems do this by default, usually by setting the environment variable LANG to "en_US.UTF-8", or another language.  Also, make sure your filenames are encoded in UTF-8.

With that set, there's no need to mess with encodings to access files in any language, even in Python 2.x.

```
[~/test] echo $LANG
en_US.UTF-8
[~/test] echo testing > 漢字
[~/test] python2.6
Python 2.6.2 (release26-maint, Apr 19 2009, 01:56:41)
[GCC 4.3.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> os.stat("漢字")
posix.stat_result(st_mode=33188, st_ino=548583333L, st_dev=2049L, st_nlink=1, st_uid=1000, st_gid=1000, st_size=8L, st_atime=1263634240, st_mtime=1263634230, st_ctime=1263634230)
>>> os.stat(u"漢字")
posix.stat_result(st_mode=33188, st_ino=548583333L, st_dev=2049L, st_nlink=1, st_uid=1000, st_gid=1000, st_size=8L, st_atime=1263634240, st_mtime=1263634230, st_ctime=1263634230)
>>> open("漢字").read()
'testing\n'
>>> open(u"漢字").read()
'testing\n'
```

If this doesn't work, run "locale"; if the values are "C" instead of en_US.UTF-8, you may not have the locale installed correctly.

If you're in Windows, I think Unicode filenames should always just work (at least for the os/posix modules), since the Unicode file API in Windows is supported transparently.

Comment: I try the same with letter ß in the console, and it works, but when I execute it in a script it doesn't, I get IOError, no such file or directory, and the character has been encoded to '\xc3\x9f'

Answer (score 6):

None of these solutions worked for me. However, I did find the (a?) solution. There is yet another place in Apache settings where one has to add the locale setting if one uses WSGI. [Official docs are here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/). Add the following two lines to `/etc/apache2/envvars` (on Ubuntu):

```
export LANG='en_US.UTF-8'
export LC_ALL='en_US.UTF-8'
```

Then restart the server. This solved my problem.

Answer (score 2):

It is easy to get this kind of error when running service (E.g: gunicorn) from Upstart.

To fix that, set env in upstart file:

```
env LANG=en_US.UTF-8
env LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8
env LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

Answer (score 1):

Encode to the filesystem encoding before calling. See the `locale` module.

Comment: thanks for this. But I'm not sure I follow. Are you saying that I can tell Django that an uploaded file's name should be adapted? I don't see anything about this in the locale module.

Comment: You have to use the native system's encoding to refer to files. Try `locale.nl_langinfo(locale.CODESET)`.

Answer (score 1):

Change your http server to use UTF-8 locale. For example, I use apache2 on CentOS. I changed */etc/sysconfig/httpd* locale setting by HTTPD_LANG:

```
# CentOS use /etc/sysconfig/httpd to config environment variables.
#
# By default, the httpd process is started in the C locale; to
# change the locale in which the server runs, the HTTPD_LANG
# variable can be set.
#
# HTTPD_LANG=C
HTTPD_LANG=en_US.UTF-8  # you can change to your locale.
```

Comment: This has no effect for me (Django 1.10, running on Ubuntu 16.04). I still get the error and I cannot use OP's solution because I'm not doing the `os.path` call, Django is.

Comment: Apache config may depend what kind of OS you use. Ubuntu may use a different path.