# Sending file as an attachment

Tags: python, bottle

in my attempt to send a file to the user iam using the following:

```
return static_file( filename, root='/home/nikos/public_html/static/files' )
```

But when it comes to .pdf files it opens them to the browser instead of just sendign the file and all other files like .docx it sends them with the filename being just 'file' and not with original file's filename.

How can i send the files properly as attachments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [mentioned in the docs](https://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/tutorial.html) you can simply pass a `download=True` argument and that should be it.

e.g.

```
return static_file(filename, root='/static/files', download=True)
```

You can also suggest a different filename for the download and pass that instead of `True`, e.g. `download="Custom "+filename`

Comment: Thank you very much, the only problem now is that iam getting a `Unicode EncodingError` if i try to download Greek filenames. Can you help me on this issue too?

Comment: I can help on that as well, but will need more details on the error. If you feel it's a small thing then add it to this question, else create a new one.

Comment: Thank you i have opened a new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52475270/telling-apache-to-display-unicode-properly

Comment: Actually after trying it, selecting the file for download i get an error `file not found` Any idea why it says that?

Comment: Nope, no idea, maybe try `download=filename` instead for the same file, see if that works. Or, try printing the filename so that you may debug further.

Comment: That worked very well! When it comes to latin fileanmes though it returnes me the error `UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 14-33: ordinal not in range(128)` Any idea how can i send files with greek filenames as well?